# How do I call OWASP Java HTML Sanitize in the most restrictive mode?

Tags: java, html, owasp

In the below code am I calling sanitizer correctly? I'm having trouble satisfying veracode - it says its still vulnerable to XXS and I'm trying the above code next but I'm not sure I'm calling it right.

```java
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
            .requireRelNofollowOnLinks()
            .build();
String SafeOutputLine = policy.sanitize(unsafeoutputLine+"\n");
```

What would be the most restrictive way to call sanitizer? I'd rather try something super restrictive first to see if the issue is remediated first.

I appreciate any help

I tried this code hoping it would be more restrictive but my security tool says there's still a xxs attack possible

```java
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()

                   .allowElements("")

                   .allowUrlProtocols("")

                   .allowAttributes("").onElements("")

                   .requireRelNofollowOnLinks()

                   .toFactory();
```